# Toggle CoreLocation using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to toggle CoreLocation on and off when you press a button in my swift app. When the app loads, this is how I turn it on

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

This works great. It prompts the user and then updates my location on the map. However, if you were to choose "No" when it requests, I want to be able to then turn it back on again. I thought this would be as easy as just requesting for authorization again but it isn't working. I have a method that gets called when a button is pressed to turn the location on.

The code for this method is essentially exactly the same. Is there something different I need to do once the authorization status has been set initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you were to choose "No" when it requests, I want to be able to then turn it back on again

Once the user has chosen to refuse you authorization, you cannot magically contradict the user, and (alas) you *cannot* make the system's authorization dialog appear ever again.

The best you can do is put up *your own* dialog (i.e. an alert) *begging* the user to go to Settings and flip the switch to give you authorization. You can even *take* the user to Settings (new in iOS 8). But you can't get that system authorization dialog again.